# Compress a group of images

Tags: image, compression

Is it possible to compress a large group of images to reduce their combined file size a considerable amount, but in such a way they can be accessed from a C# application?

The images themselves are GIFs so I think they are as compressed as they're going to get individually, so just packing them all into a zip file won't help much. However they are all fairly similar (being frames of an swf animation) so theoretically, in combining them, it would seem there is room for compression... is there a way it could be done?

Comment: Without writing customized non-trivial software, *i guess no*. As each gif-encoder already has the entropy-coder pipeline it's too late to work on the output from that. You would need some software which is explicitly designed for joint-compression and i'm sceptical anyone was motivated to design such a thing. Maybe there is some encoder which allows not doing entropy-compression (not sure what the standard says) and a follow-up zipping over a bigger set *may help*. Maybe you can flatten-out everything uncompressed and do follow-up compression.But cost-benefit is probably bad.

Comment: Maybe dropping GIF and going for an alternative codec might be a better idea. Not sure though if lossless H265 or similar would support all the GIF cases (color-format, and co.) and how much it would help.